# PhantomJS doesn't exit on onResourceTimeout callback

Tags: javascript, windows, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS 2.0.0 on Windows 7 and I don't quite understand why PhantomJS only returns for onResourceError callback, while not for onResourceTimeout callback.

```js
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();

// Invoked when a web page was unable to load resource.
page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
   system.stderr.writeLine('onResourceError url: ' + resourceError.url);
   phantom.exit();
};

// Invoked when there is a time out when load resource on the web page.
page.onResourceTimeout = function(request) {
   system.stderr.writeLine('onResourceTimeout url: ' + request.url);
   phantom.exit();
};

// Resource Time out
page.settings.resourceTimeout = 5000; // 5 seconds time out

// Load page with 10 sec. delay
page.open('http://httpbin.org/delay/10');
```

With PhantomJS 2.0.0, The above code will print

```
onResourceTimeout url: http://httpbin.org/delay/10
onResourceError url: http://httpbin.org/delay/10
```

`phantom.exit()` seem not to be call on `page.onResourceTimeout()`

With PhantomJS 1.9.8, The above code will print

```
onResourceTimeout url: http://httpbin.org/delay/10
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL file://OnRessourceTimeOut.js. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

**EDIT :** If I replace `system.stderr.writeLine` by `console.log`, With PantomJS 2.0.0, It's OK, the output is

```
onResourceTimeout url: http://httpbin.org/delay/10
```

Comment: Does PhantomJS 1.9.x have the same behavior? What's the time difference between the two prints? Exit takes a little bit of time, so the second line can be printed.

Comment: There is no ime difference between the two prints. I update my post with PhantomJS 1.9.8 test.

Comment: So, there isn't really a problem there. My is guess that exiting happens asynchronously so that other code can be executed, but it's fast enough that not that much code is executed. This might also be related to the solution of a bug that was introduced in 1.9.8 which you see here as "Unsafe JavaScript ...".

Comment: I edit my post with replace `system.stderr.writeLine` by `console.log`. OK for 1.9.8 Issue:  Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame in 1.9.8 #12697 (https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12697)